# Disable unused method in gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to disable the unused method in gem that is present in my rails app. Is it possible?

Comment: What gem, what method, what do you mean by "disable", and why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove_method` http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/remove_method

I'm curious why you want to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method and let it behave differently or the below ruby built in approach:

`undef_method` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-undef_method

or

`remove_method` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#remove_method-method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove method from the particular class (not from the ancestors) you should use [remove_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-remove_method).

If also you want to search superclasses and mixed-in modules for a receiver then use [undef_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-undef_method).

There's also [undef](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-undef) keyword which acts similar as `remove_method` but probably a bit faster. It receives method name (not symbol or string).

**Usage:**

```
class Parent
  def foo; end

  def baz; end
end

class Child < Parent
  def bar; end
end

Child.send :remove_method, :bar # I use send for space-economy. 
                                # You should reopen the class
Child.new.bar # => NoMethodError
Child.send :remove_method, :foo # NameError: method `foo' not defined in Child

Child.send :undef_method, :foo
Child.new.foo # => NoMethodError

Parent.class_eval { undef baz } 
Parent.new.baz # => NoMethodError
```